# passing data to angular.js from PHP

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs

I have my angular.js app built with a php page that contains a variable that my app needs on load. The angular app on load then uses this variable to fetch more data using a POST. What is the best practice for passing a variable to angular? Also, how can I tell angular to not run the initial controller function until after it has the variable loaded? Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to pass variables and data from PHP to JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23740548/how-to-pass-variables-and-data-from-php-to-javascript)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your case probably the best way is to write it down with something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var _yourSpecialVar = <?php echo $variable ?>;
</script>
```

And in Angular:

```
$window._yourSpecialVar
```

EDIT:

For example in an Angular controller:

```
angular.module('app').controller('YourController', ['$scope', '$window', function($scope, $window) {
    $scope.myVar = $window._yourSpecialVar
}]);
```

Comment: is the angular part inside the controller file?

Comment: where you want, just inject $window

Answer (score 0):

Use `ng-init` to pass data from php to angular. It allows you to evaluate an expression in the current scope.

```
<div ng-init="<?PHP {name='John'}?>">
```

This directly goes to the scope.